# Adding multiple nodegroups to eks

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I would like to add multiple nodegroups to eks, each one with different labels. I have successfully deployed a second cloud formation stack and can see the new ec2 instances, but I cannot see the new nodes in the k8s dashboard. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

I was able to fix this by going back and updating the aws-auth configmap, adding a second role map:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: OLD ARN
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
      groups:
        - system:bootstrappers
        - system:nodes
    - rolearn: NEW ARN
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
      groups:
        - system:bootstrappers
        - system:nodes
```